# Why is this inner join SQL block failing?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, inner-join

Receiving `incorrect syntax near as` when running this `inner join`.  Need to determine why and cannot.  Please point out where this goes wrong:

Relevant SQL Code

```
from 

(   
    (
        (dbo.task inner join dbo.projwbs on dbo.task.proj_id=dbo.projwbs.wbs_id) as tmptb1
    inner join
        (dbo.task inner join dbo.project on dbo.task.proj_id=dbo.project.proj_id) as tmptb2
        on dbo.tmptb1.proj_id=dbo.tmptb2.proj_id as dbo.tmptb3
    )
    inner join
(
        (dbo.task inner join dbo.rsrc on dbo.task.rsrc_id=dbo.rsrs.rsrc_id) as tmptb4)
        on tmptb3.proj_id=tmptb4.proj_id
    )
```

Comment: I formatted your code block and you may need a trailing parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing something... but since these are all `inner joins`, I'm not sure what the blocks are giving you that a simplified version wouldn't also do:

```
from 
    dbo.task t
    inner join dbo.projwbs pw on t.proj_id=pw.wbs_id 
    inner join dbo.project p on t.proj_id=p.proj_id
    inner join dbo.rsrc r on t.rsrc_id=r.rsrc_id
```

Comment: thanks. Michael and @bluefeet Just found out we can join tables in a linear way like this and my earlier belief was we can join only 2 tables at a time.

I simplified my code this way and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks to have too many parentheses but it is hard to tell exactly what you are doing. So I would alter it to use something similar to this:

```
select *
from 
(
    select *
    from
    (   
        select *
        FROM dbo.task 
        inner join dbo.projwbs 
            on dbo.task.proj_id=dbo.projwbs.wbs_id
    ) as tmptb1
    inner join
    (
        select *
        from dbo.task 
        inner join dbo.project 
            on dbo.task.proj_id=dbo.project.proj_id
    ) as tmptb2
        on tmptb1.proj_id=tmptb2.proj_id
) as tmptb3
inner join
(
    select *
    from dbo.task 
    inner join dbo.rsrc 
        on dbo.task.rsrc_id=dbo.rsrs.rsrc_id
) as tmptb4
    on tmptb3.proj_id=tmptb4.proj_id
```

Replace the `SELECT *` with the columns that you want from each table.

I am not sure why you are doing all of those subqueries to get the data, you should be able to use:

```
select *
from dbo.task t
inner join dbo.projwbs w
  on t.proj_id=w.wbs_id
inner join dbo.project p
  on t.proj_id=p.proj_id
inner join dbo.rsrc r
  on t.rsrc_id = r.rsrc_id
```